# Title Case: Unable to Log In to System

Tags: prepositions, capitalization

How can I correctly capitalize this e-mail title: Unable to Log In to System

For bonus points, what are the parts of speech for the short words? I'm having particular difficulty with the word "to".

Comment: Bear in mind also that title case isn't compulsory for email subject lines ( http://www.syntaxis.com/email-subject-lines/ and see also the answer here https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/369829/should-words-in-email-subjects-be-capitalized ).  Personally I think title case is ugly (look at "This Is How He Finally Got the Hell Out of Mexico!", which is correct Chicago style - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169648/how-to-capitalize-get-out-of-in-a-title-according-to-cmos/170829#170829 ). So I avoid it except when it's strictly required.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use sentence case:

> Unable to log in to system

(Actually, I prefer "log into", but see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5302/log-in-to-or-log-into-or-login-to - where the top-voted answer favours "in to" but admits that "into" is probably just as widely used.)

The rules for title case vary slightly among different style guides.  It could be:

> Unable to Log In to System

Lower case is usual for the shortest words ( http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2012/03/title-case-and-sentence-case-capitalization-in-apa-style.html ), which would point to "in".  However, although normally a preposition, "in" here is part of a phrasal verb and is behaving adverbially, so Chicago style at least would recommend "In" ( https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169648/how-to-capitalize-get-out-of-in-a-title-according-to-cmos/170829#170829 ).  I think that "Log In to System" looks slightly better than "Log in to System", although I dislike both.

You also asked about the parts of speech.  You can find these in a dictionary.  Traditionally, both "to"s would be classed as prepositions, although the first "to" is really better regarded as an infinitive-marking particle (as is now recognised by Oxford: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/to ).